# Is it possible to implement producer consumer using only mutex without condition variables?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, producer-consumer

I would like to know if there is any way to implement producer consumer using phtreads in c using only `pthread_mutex` variables to control access to the buffer that must have finite size N, using `phtread_cond` variables is not allowed.

I have read in another forum a post from 2016 where someone stated that there was a solution (I guess optimal) using three mutex, I would like to find this solution if it does actually exists. However any solution using only mutex (as much as needed) would be valid.

link to that post https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333215/producer-consumer-problem-with-2-mutexes

Comment: You may want to investigate `pthread_kill` as a way to wake up a thread (a poor man's substitute for `pthread_cond_signal`).

Comment: "I have read in another forum a post ..." -- link to the post?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if there is any way to implement producer consumer

Of course there is, it's just not going to be efficient or particularly fast.

```
void producer()
{
  while (1) {
    lock();
    while (q_has_space()) produce_one_item();
    unlock();
    sleep();  // The longer you sleep, the less CPU you burn, but the longer the 
              // delay between consumer freeing up space and producer putting more
              // items in the queue. 
  }
}

void consumer()
{
  while (1) {
    lock();
    while (q_has_items()) consume_one_item();
    unlock();
    sleep();  // Same considerations as in producer
  }
}
```

Above pseudo-code has additional inefficiencies: both `produce` and `consume` are running inside the lock, which is usually very sub-optimal. Fixing that is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @Pepe You are moving goal posts. Instead of commenting on this answer, please edit your question stating your actual requirements.